# jQuery 1.11.1 or jQuery 3.1.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, version

The jQuery download page recommends version 3.1.0, but [jQuery latest](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) is version 1.11.1. Did the developers not change the latest version, or is 1.11.1 the latest version?

Also, can I get jQuery 1.11.1 API? Just wondering...

Comment: `Also, can I get jQuery 1.11.1 API?` - isn't that the one in your link? seems the "latest" link you posted is years old - maybe the devs at jquery don't even know it's still there

Comment: Possibly, and I never linked 1.11.1 API. jQuery does NOT have inline API

Answer (score 6):

As Kaleb has said, 3.1.0 is newer than 1.11.1. And to answer your first question.

> Did the developers not change the latest version?

From JQuery blog which can be found [here](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/):

> The jquery-latest.js and jquery-latest.min.js files were meant to provide a simple way to download the latest released version of jQuery core. Instead, some developers include this version directly in their production sites, exposing users to the risk of a broken site each time a new version of jQuery is released.
>
> To mitigate the risk of “breaking the web”, the jQuery team decided back in 2013 that jquery-latest.js could not be upgraded to the 2.0 branch even though that is technically the latest version. There would just be too many sites that would mysteriously stop working with older versions of Internet Explorer, and many of those sites may not be maintained today.
>
> As jQuery adoption has continued to grow, even that safeguard seems insufficient to protect against careless use of http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js. So we have decided to stop updating this file, as well as the minified copy, keeping both files at version 1.11.1 forever.

Comment: Thank you very much, I expected people to be like "Are you stupid?" but apparently not. Although the below answer has an argument